How to automatically instantiate template functions
I have some template functions with only one template parameter.
// add.cpp
template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b) {
  // do something
}

// func1.cpp
template <typename T>
void func1(int n) {
  T t;
  // do something
}

// func2.cpp
template <typename T>
void func2(ClassHasNoDefaultConstructor c) {
  T t;
  // do something
}

// Some template functions will be added in the future

I have to instantiate each function with a couple of types. Here is the trivial way.
// add.cpp
int add(int, int);
double add(double, double);
std::complex<double> add(std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>);

// func1.cpp
void func1<int>(int);
void func1<double>(int);
void func1<std::complex<double>>(int);

// func2.cpp
void func2<int>(ClassHasNoDefaultConstructor);
void func2<double>(ClassHasNoDefaultConstructor);
void func2<std::complex<double>>(ClassHasNoDefaultConstructor);

The trivial way works. However if I want to support the fourth type, I will need to modified all source files (add.cpp, func1.cpp and func2.cpp in the example above).
I want to automatically explicitly instantiate those template functions with all supported types. The code below demonstrates what I want to do, but it is invalid.
template <template <typename> typename Func>
class Instantiate{
  static constexpr auto f_int = Func<int>;
  static constexpr auto f_double = Func<double>;
  static constexpr auto f_complex = Func<std::complex<double>>;
};


// The lines below throw compile errors because functions cannot be the template template parameters
Instantiate<add>;
Instantiate<func1>;
Instantiate<func2>;
// ... 

By doing this, I only have to add one line to support the fourth type.
I know defining template functions in the source files is a weird practice, however this practive significantly reduce compile time when the definition of the function is modified in my case.
There are some posts about instantiating template functions, but they are not what I need.

Template function as a template argument
Automating explicit template instantiation

Is there any way to automatically instantiate any template functions having one template parameter?

would you be ok with making the funtion templates into class templates (with operator()) ? Class templates are so much nicer than function templates

Template functions should not even be in cpp files, they should be in header files. And then it would also be fine to include them.

Look into niebloids.

use a template template parameter. i do not understand your wording for dynamic instantiation. overall i do not get your idea.

This question is similar to: What are some uses of template template parameters?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I updated the question to make it clear.

int add(int, int); is not an explicit instantiation but just a declaration of a non-template function. func1.cpp/func2.cpp are correct :)

It is impossible to automatically generate explicit instantiations in C++. Each explicit instantiation must be written as a declaration by itself.
Your idea of forcing implicit instantiation via a class template doesn't work even in in principle, because implicit instantiations cannot replace explicit instantiations. If you have implicit instantiation in one translation unit, but not another that requires the instantiation, then the program is still ill-formed (no diagnostic required).
The only way to somewhat automate this (outside of external code generation) is to use preprocessor macros.
However, the normal approach here would be to not use explicit instantiation at all, but instead define the templates in header files so that implicit instantiation can happen automatically in every translation unit where it is required. Then no explicit instantiations are needed at all.
Especially for simple functions like add you want them defined in the header file anyway, because otherwise (assuming no LTO is used) the compiler won't be able to inline them for optimization.
